# How do I check the spelling of a input through the help of a list?

Tags: python

I want to make a program that takes a user input of a name of a fruit, compares it to a premade list of fruits and tells the user if the spelling of the fruit they entered is correct or not. What is the best way of doing that?

I have a list made of common fruit. and I tried comparing each letter of the input string to the list. But I think that compared it to all of the fruit names. Sorry if this is a really stupid question but I am new to programming.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYBJA.png)

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: `if fruit in list` should be able to tell you if the user input matches anything in the list.

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
fruit=input("Enter name of fruit: ")
lis=['Apple','Banana','Apricot']

if fruit.title() in lis:
    print("Spelling of fruit is correct")
else:
    print("Spelling of fruit is wrong")
```

**Output:-**

```
Enter name of fruit: Banana
Spelling of fruit is correct

Enter name of fruit: banan
Spelling of fruit is wrong
```

Note- In `lis` all elements are in **capitalize**[i.e First letter is capital].. also if you want the user to input till it wants you can use `while` see the below code..!

**Code:**

```
lis=['Apple','Banana','Apricot']

while True:
    user_input=input("Enter name of fruit or if you want to end please right [end/End]: ")
    if user_input.lower()=="end":
        break
    elif user_input.title() in lis:
        print("Spelling of fruit is correct")
    else:
        print("Spelling of fruit is wrong")
```

**Output:**

```
Enter name of fruit or if you want to end please right [end/End]: apple
Spelling of fruit is correct
Enter name of fruit or if you want to end please right [end/End]: Apricot
Spelling of fruit is correct
Enter name of fruit or if you want to end please right [end/End]: Banan
Spelling of fruit is wrong
Enter name of fruit or if you want to end please right [end/End]: end
```